# wp ajax execution time aborted 30 sec

Tags: ajax

I have problem with max execution time. When I am doing ajax request it shows aborted 30 sec. But I have changed php max execution time in .user.ini, .htaccess and php executes more time, but ajax not. What should I need to do ?

Comment: may still be a server issue - did you restart apache/nginx after your changes?

Answer (score 1):

there is a property timeout for ajax and you can use it.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: admin_ajax_url,
    error: function(){
        // will fire when timeout is reached
    },
    success: function( response ){
        //do something
    },
    timeout: 3000 // sets timeout to 3 seconds
});
```